# What is !! in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code is used to verify if cached data exist.

```
const cached = await cache.get(session.sid);
const out = {
    valid: !! cached
};

if (out.valid) {
    out.credentials = cached.account;
}
```

Comment: Its a way of casting a value to a bolean.

Comment: See https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#explicitly-----boolean

Comment: Beware, `!!'false'` returns true. This is a neat shorthand, but I'd be very very careful of using it at all.